# Java LocalTime achieve thread safety

Tags: java, java-time

Documentation of [LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) says it is thread-safe. I understand that it in itself is thread-safe.
But would it be thread-safe if I were to share it among many threads like this?

```
public class Timesheet {

private static boolean run = true;

private static LocalTime activity;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        activity =  LocalTime.now();
    }

    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        activity =  LocalTime.now();
    }

    try {
        while (run) {
           Thread.sleep(12000);
           run = false; 
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        
    } finally {
        //print activity
    }
}
```

I am trying to get accurate timing. If I were to check the timing of activity in main thread. would it be accurate?

edit:

I understand now why my code is not thread-safe. If I were to manipulate LocalTime instance inside synchronized code, would that make my code thread-safe?

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
    synchronized (activity) {
        activity = LocalTime.now();
    }
}
```

Comment: The version with the synchronized block is not thread safe, because synchronizing on `activity` is not helpful here.  You must synchronize on something that remains fixed.

Comment: Can you please give me a hint what I can do to make my  program thread safe? I thought synchronizing `activity` instance is enough no matter how many times the reference of memory address it refers to changes. @LouisWasserman. I am unable to understand this hint of yours "You must synchronize on something that remains fixed."

Comment: My reasoning is that it does not matter which thread accesses `activity`, that thread will lock `activity` (so other threads cannot update its value and they have to wait), assign it new LocalTime, and carry on. To me, `activity` is fixed.

Comment: If my logic were to be correct, then activity will always print accurate time.

Comment: Doing `synchronized (something) { ... }` is correct, but the value of `activity` changes, so it's not a good `something`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LocalDate` is not just threadsafe.

It is **immutable**.

Thread safety, in terms of a type, is referring to the notion of what happens when you mutate the object - you do this, **always**, via a dot: `someExprThatRefersToThatObject.field = foo` or `someExprThatRefersToThatObject.method()` where that method will result in the object being changed somehow.

None of these things are possible with LocalDate. There are no methods that modify things, and no fields for you to modify. Instead, LocalDate has methods that don't modify the object at all; instead, they return new ones. For example, `someDate.plusDays(1)` doesn't change `someDate` at all. It just returns a new `LocalDate` object instead.

That means *YOUR* references are changing if you write code like `activity = LocalTime.now();` and the thread safety of that has zip squat to do with LocalTime, it's all to do with you.

Specifically, in your example, that is not thread safe. It doesn't matter what the type of `activity` is. It could be `int`, `String`, `LocalTime`, `ArrayList`, or anything else you please: Changing a field without establishing a comes-before relationship with code that reads it, **is broken**, and you're doing just that.

Some methods may decree they are thread safe. As a general rule, trying to share data between threads is considerably more complicated than just calling a bunch of those methods and praying.